# Browsers don't honor a:visited { text-decoration: none; }

Tags: css, css-selectors

I can't remove underlining from visited links. In my computer, the Fiddle below shows **black, underlined** text for the visited link in any browser (current versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE).

```css
a:link       { color: red;   text-decoration: underline; }
a:visited    { color: black; text-decoration: none;      }
```

```html
<p><a href="http://www.nevervisited.com">This link is not visited.</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.google.com">This is link is visited.</a></p>
```

This is Chrome's inspector for the visited link.

[image]

I suspect `a:visited` being grayed out has something to do with this, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265555/what-does-it-mean-when-a-css-rule-is-grayed-out-in-chromes-element-inspector) about grayed out styles didn't do anything for me, though it helped many others.

These answers ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823388/4850), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11481121/4850)) suggest the spec doesn't care about child elements' `text-decoration` when their ancestor has it defined, but I don't think this is the case here. My `<a>`s don't have underlined parents, nor am I using pseudo-*elements*, but pseudo-*classes*.

Also, why does Chrome apply `a:link` to the visited link, if [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors#link-pseudo-classes) says that

> The two states [`a:link` and `a:visited`] are mutually exclusive.

Maybe this has to do with user agents hiding private info from websites, like W3C suggests right after the previous quote? This:

> **Note.** It is possible for style sheet authors to abuse the `:link` and `:visited` pseudo-classes to determine which sites a user has visited without the user's consent.
>
> UAs may therefore treat all links as unvisited links, or implement other measures to preserve the user's privacy while rendering visited and unvisited links differently.

Comment: It appears to be related to the security issue you noted. See also https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only CSS property you can apply on `a:visited` links in most Webkit-based browsers (like Safari) or Blink-based (Chrome and Opera) is `color`. Anything else won't work. It has something to do with browser history stealing. You can read more about it from here:

http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2013/May/13

However you can change the style of all links with `a {text-decoration: none;}`.

The selector itself is not dangerous, but if you combine it with Javascript's functions like [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) things can get pretty ugly and by ugly I mean that other users can view and read your personal browser history.

Mozilla (Gecko engine) [limited the selector properties](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/) to `color`, `background-color`, `border-*-color`.

Answer (score 1):

You still can get the same effect by setting

```
text-decoration-color
```

Simply, set decoration color to your background color. Line will still be there, but wont be visible.

For example in a white background page, use:

```
text-decoration-color: white;
```