# Why is a CSS rule grayed out in Chrome inspector

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to edit an element but the style I need to edit is grayed out for some reason. What could be causing this? The [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265555/what-does-it-mean-when-a-css-rule-is-grayed-out-in-chromes-element-inspector) does not seem to address this case.

[image]

Comment: I think it's about inline style?

Comment: See https://crbug.com/922181 - it happens in Chrome if the ruleset was created programmatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265555/what-does-it-mean-when-a-css-rule-is-grayed-out-in-chromes-element-inspector [Duplicate]

Comment: @AndrewKovalchuk I mentioned that other question, it does not seem to address this case - the grayed out rule in the answer is user agent stylesheet, while in my case it is a custom style.

Comment: Close Chrome and open again. Worked for me after some hair pulling.

Answer (score 2):

1. Crossed out styles are being overridden by another CSS rule
2. Grayed out text is a rule that isn't applied (eg pre-fixed for another browser)
3. A gray background represents **Read Only** styles that can't be edited in the inspector.

See this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842255/chrome-dev-tools-showing-a-css-rule-on-a-grey-background-why) for more details. Chrome devtool [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-styles)

Comment: I can't find anything in that question or documentation that explains why the style is considered read-only. I got that it is read-only since I can't edit it, but that doesn't explain *why* I can't edit it.

Comment: I've added a real answer there.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that. Guess it is a bug then after all.

Answer (score -2):

It means that this rule was overrode by some other rule.

In your case, all of the prefixed rules (`-webkit`/`-moz`...) were overrode by the standard `user-select` rule.

Comment: It's not so much that it's overridden as Chrome *ignores* `-moz`, `-ms`, etc. prefixed rules entirely, as they're not intended for Chrome at all. It *does* listen to the `-webkit` prefixed one as it's Webkit based.