# Is it possible to locate the parent CSS which causes a rule to be grayed out value in Chrome inspector?

Tags: css, web-inspector

I'm editing an existing website's footer to match the width of the part above it. That line is grayed out in Chrome web inspector. How do I find the CSS which informs this width?

[image]

[What does it mean when a CSS rule is grayed out in Chrome's element inspector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265555/what-does-it-mean-when-a-css-rule-is-grayed-out-in-chromes-element-inspector) answers the question of why this is happening, but now how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the **Computed** tab, which is completely different than the **Styles** one the other Q/A was referring to.

In the **Computed** tab, you get the same results as if you called [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) on the element. As you may know, these values are not necessarily the authored ones.

A greyed out value there means that this value has not been assigned by any explicit rule, but for instance here, it's because the content of the page made it have a **computed** width of `981px`. 
If you did set a rule on this element, you would have had the collapsible menu telling which rule has been applied.

```css
.with-rule {
  width: auto; /* even if authored as auto */
}
```

```html
<div class="no-rule">My width will be greyed out in the Computed Tab</div>
<div class="with-rule">I will have  a collapsible menu</div>
```

Now maybe you should prefer the **Styles** tab, which will give you more information about the actual **rules** that are applied on your element.